# DataStore: Issue when querying entities within a transaction given the parent

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

The entities are all sub classes for this abstract class, and it was working until lately where it returns an empty result, here is the code where it was working, and then down the code that works

```
public abstract AbstractParentEntity{
    @Index @Parent private Ref<T> parentKey;

    protected void setParent(Class<T> parentClazz, T parent){

       Key<T> key = Key.create(parentClazz, parent.getGuid());

      this.parentKey = Ref.create(key);
    }
}
```

And it queries for the entities:

```
Key<V> parent = Key.create(parentClazz, parentKey);

Query<T> query = ofy().load().type(clazz).ancestor(ref);
QueryResultIterator<T> iterator = query.iterator();
```

Code that works:

```
public abstract AbstractParentEntity{
    @Index @Parent private Ref<T> parentKey;

    protected void setParent(Class<T> parentClazz, T parent){
       this.parentKey = Ref.create(parent);
    }
 }
```

And it queries for the entities:

```
Ref<V> ref = createRef(parent);
Query<T> query = ofy().load().type(clazz).ancestor(ref);
QueryResultIterator<T> iterator = query.iterator();
```

I can't use the method that works because it basically changes the parent and would cause to loose the entities.

Snippet of data I use ( ignoring the @Id and other setters and getters )

```
class AncesorModel{
}

class ParentModel extends AbstractParentEntity<AncesorModel>{

}

class ChildModel extends AbstractParentEntity<ParentModel>{

}
// create new AncesorModel object and save it in DS
// create new ParentModel object that has the AncesorModel as parent and save it in DS
// create several ChildModel objects that have ParentModel as parent and save it in DS
//query for ChildModel by using the AncesorModel 

Key<V> ancKey = Key.create(AncesorModel.class , ancId);

Query<T> query = ofy().load().type(ChildModel.class).ancestor(ancKey);
QueryResultIterator<ChildModel> iterator = query.iterator();
```

Any idea why using the first method returns empty result ?

Here is a clean example:

```
@Entity
public class ChildModel {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Parent
    private Ref<ParentModel> par;
    public ParentModel getPar(){
        return this.par.get();
    }

    public void setPar(ParentModel par){
        Key<ParentModel> key = Key.create(ParentModel.class, par.getId());
        this.par = Ref.create(key);
    }
}

@Entity
public class ParentModel {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Parent 
    private Ref<AncesorModel> anc;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public AncesorModel getAnc(){
        return this.anc.get();
    }

    public void setAnc(AncesorModel anc){
        Key<AncesorModel> key = Key.create(AncesorModel.class, anc.getId());
        this.anc = Ref.create(key);
    }
}

@Entity
public class AncestorModel{

    @Id
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

AncestorModel anc = new AncestorModel();
anc.setId(generateId());
ofy().save().entity(anc).now();

anc = ofy().load().key(Key.create(AncestorModel.class, anc.getId())).now();

ParentModel par = new ParentModel();
par.setAnc(anc);
par.setId(generateId());
ofy().save().entity(par).now();

Key<AncestorModel> ancKey = Key.create(AncestorModel.class, anc.getId());
par = ofy().load().type(ParentModel.class).parent(ancKey).id(par.getId()).now();

ChildModel child1 = new ChildModel();
child1.setId(generateId());
child1.setPar(par);
ofy().save().entity(child1).now();

ChildModel child2 = new ChildModel();
child2.setId(generateId());
child2.setPar(par);
ofy().save().entity(child2).now();

ChildModel child3 = new ChildModel();
child3.setId(GUIDUtils.generateGuid());
child3.setPar(par);
ofy().save().entity(child3).now();

ancKey = Key.create(AncestorModel.class, anc.getId());

//empty result
List<ChildModel> childs = ofy().load().type(ChildModel.class).ancestor(ancKey).list();

//3 entities in the result
childs = ofy().load().type(ChildModel.class).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the section about keys here:

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Concepts

The parent is part of the identity of the entity; you can never change it just like you can never change the id. Perhaps you want to use a separate indexed field instead?

Also: You don't need to `@Index` parent fields.

Comment: I understand that changing the parent is like changing the id, and that what I meant in "I can't use the method that works because it basically changes the parent and would cause to loose the entities."

For the index, I thought that is needed to query entities for given parent, but also removing the @Index didn't help.

Comment: Can you reformulate the question? It's not clear what you are asking. What does "stopped working" mean?

Comment: I edited the question. Basically retrieving the entities using the first method returns empty result.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still can't understand what you are asking. What data did you put in the db? Try to boil this down to a self-contained test case. BTW some of your code example won't compile; the `Key.create()` signature is wrong.

Comment: I did create a clean project and still getting the same.
This code compiles properly, and Key.create() signature is correct.
I just put a sample data, see above.

Comment: I just added a clean example, check it out.

Comment: Your `ChildModel` does not declare `@Parent` on the `par` field.

Comment: I fixed that in the example. You are not looking at the big picture, if I use the same code but declare the parent as Ref<ParentEntity> parent , and assign a value to it by Ref<ParentEntity> parent = Ref.create(parentEntity) , and do the same for ParentEntity ancestor, then it would work. ( Of course I have to query for child and parent models given the parent entity instead of parent ID as described )

Comment: I can't read your mind to figure out which of the problems in your examples are the "real" problems and which ones are just typos. The next thing that's wrong with your example is that you aren't properly creating the key here: `Key.create(ParentModel.class, par.getId());` You need something like `Key.create(par.getAnc().getK(), ParentModel.class, par.getId());`.

Comment: Your code will probably clean itself up if you just gave every entity a `getKey()` method that implements the correct logic.

Comment: Well, the code in AbstractParentEntity shows that it always sets the parent, and the code you mentioned is based on your request and it's not actual one, and it's very basic. However I was able to fix the issue by using Key.create(par.getAnc().getId(), ParentModel.class, par.getId()), so basically passing the parent id when creating the key, so if you move this in separate answer then I can accept the answer. much thanks